# Why function defined in closure is inaccessible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, closures

Why function defined in closure is not accessible in directive and watch callback methods? Other variables defined in same scope are accessible.

**Note:** If I call `'_personname'` function once either in directive callback or in `_link` method, then it will be accessible later on.

Not sure what is going wrong.

```js
    'use strict';

    define('directives/vkValidator', ['angular', 'directives/vkForm'], function(angular, vkForm) {

    var moduleName = 'mdlDrVkForm';

    var RE_NAME = /^[a-z][a-z\.\s]+?$/i;

    function _personname(val) {
        return RE_NAME.test(val);
    }
    var directiveNname = 'vkValidator';

    angular.module(moduleName).directive(directiveNname,
        function() {
            // _personname is inaccessible here. Showing undefined
            // But RE_NAME is accessible
            function _link(scope, ele, attrs, model) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                    // _personname is inaccessible here as well
                    // But RE_NAME is accessible here as well
                    var fnTest = angular.isFunction('_' + attrs[directiveNname]),
                        isValid = fnTest ? fnTest(newVal) : false;

                    model.$setValidity(attrs[directiveNname], isValid);
                });
            }
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: _link
            };
        });
    return moduleName;
   });
```

Comment: What exactly is you issue?

Comment: It should be accessible because `_personname` is a global function.

Comment: Could you be more explicit, please? If you mean not accessible during debugging, then that's understandable.

Comment: @SimoEndre No, it's not.

Comment: @zeroflagL oh yes, i see that's defined inside directive, sorry, my bad.

Comment: I am trying to call `_personname` function in `watch()` but is throwing exception that "_personname is undefined"

Comment: @Vikram: what does it happen if you go with function expression var foo = function(arg) { return arg; }

Comment: `directiveNname` and `RE_NAME` both are accessible in watch() callback, but not `_personname`.

Comment: @Thalaivar: It is same behavior.           `var _personname = function _personname() {}` is behaving same.

Comment: @Vikram: Here is a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/podvffn4/1/ i am able to access... could you create a similar fiddle to play around and post here so that we can look... thanks

Comment: @All: Sorry my bad, it is showing undefined **ONLY** in developer toolbar, but works fine when use with `console.log()`. Sorry for for the inconvenience caused.